# Buttons not rendering properly inside GroupButton

Tags: android, flutter, dart, buttongroup

I'm trying to make a horizontally scrollable ButtonGroup.

I have a list of `categories` and for each one I need a button to be rendered.
My code looks like this:

```
GroupButton(
    buttons: [ 
        for(final cat in categories)
            ElevatedButton.icon(
                onPressed: () {
                    _getCategory(cat.id);
                },
                icon: cat.icon,
                label: Text(cat.name, style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            ),
        ),
    ],
)
```

I have the expected result but the buttons won't render
With this code the output looks like this:
[image]

If I don't wrap the buttons with the GroupButtons I obtain this result:

[image]

How do I render the buttons properly?

Comment: try this

GroupButton(buttons: [for (final cat in categories) ElevatedButton.icon(onPressed: () => _getCategory(cat.id), icon: cat.icon, label: Text(cat.name, style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black)))])

Comment: It seems this `group_button` package is meant to just be used with text as input. That's why it simply uses the `toString()` of the `ElevatedButton` instances. Why do you even need this `GroupButton`? It doesn't look like you need it for anything

Comment: @Ivo Pretty new to app dev, I was trying to make an horizontally scrollable button tray and this is the first thing that worked fine and seemed right

Comment: @Maveňツ removing the style didn't help :( thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @Ivo in the comments
"`It seems this group_button package is meant to just be used with text as input`"

The solution to my problem was adding a ListView with `scrollDirection` set to `horizontal`

just like this:

```
SizedBox(
    height: 40.0,
    child: ListView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    children:[

        for(final cat in categories)
            ElevatedButton.icon(
                onPressed: () {
                    _getCategory(cat.id);
                 },
                 icon: cat.icon,
                 label: Text(cat.name, style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
                 style: ButtonStyle(minimumSize: MaterialStateProperty.all<Size>(const Size(150, 40))),
            ),
        ],
    ),
),
```

The output will look like this:
[image]